# Prevent object creation when unique_together is set in Django

Tags: python, django, view

**models.py**

```
class Registrierung(models.Model):
    kategorie = models.ForeignKey(Kategorie)
    sportler = models.ForeignKey(Sportler)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('kategorie', 'sportler'),)
```

**views.py**

```
def registrieren_user(request, kategorie_id):
    kategorie = get_object_or_404(Kategorie, pk=kategorie_id)
    user = get_object_or_404(User, pk=request.user.id)
    reg = Registrierung(kategorie=kategorie, sportler=user.account.sportler)
    reg.is_valid():
        reg.save()

    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('events:events'))
```

Hi, I am trying to prevent duplicates in my database. If I make a duplicate entry of **Registrierung** in the admin-panel, I receive an error message that I can't create an object because of the unique_together relation.

How can I get this functionality in my view? Every execution of registrieren_user is saved, though it should not be possible.

**EDIT:**
My solution but I think there must be a far better way. I just use a way where I dont create a duplicate, but it still isnt prevented by standard.

**views.py** *edited*:

```
def registrieren_user(request, kategorie_id):
    kategorie = get_object_or_404(Kategorie, pk=kategorie_id)
    sportler= get_object_or_404(Sportler, pk=request.user.account.sportler.id)
    registrierungen = kategorie.registrierung_set.all()
    try:
        # Look if entry already exists
        reg = Registrierung.objects.filter(kategorie=kategorie).filter(sportler=sportler)
    except:
        # If no entry exists, create one and save it.
        reg = Registrierung(kategorie=kategorie, sportler=sportler)
        reg.save()
        context = {
            'kategorie': kategorie,
            'registrierungen': registrierungen,
        }
        return render(request, 'events/kategorie.html', context)

    # Return error_message because entry already exists.
    context = {
        'kategorie': kategorie,
        'error_message': "Du bist schon registriert.",
        'registrierungen': registrierungen,
    }
    return render(request, 'events/kategorie.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0):

Much better solution is, to enforce a **model level clean method**, like this,

```
class Registrierung(models.Model):
    kategorie = models.ForeignKey(Kategorie)
    sportler = models.ForeignKey(Sportler)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def clean(self):
        direct = Registrierung.objects.filter(kategorie = self.kategorie, sportler = self.sportler)
        reverse = Registrierung.objects.filter(kategorie = self.sportler, sportler = self.kategorie) 

        if direct.exists() or reverse.exists():
            raise ValidationError({'Exception':'Error_Message')})
```